# ShareThis links: Unable to change Facebook share title, meta tags not working

Tags: facebook, share, title, meta, sharethis

I have four ShareThis links on my page, and all of them have st_title and st_summary set. This works for everything except Facebook, which I have learned ignored the st_title tag and instead looks for meta tags. I added these meta tags to the head of my page:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="This is my website!"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://localhost:49866/EventSearchResults.aspx"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="A short description of your website"/>
```

but the title and description aren't changing. It's the same result with and without the og:url meta tag; the og:url is the exact url of my page. Both with and without the meta tags, when I click the link the title is "Localhost" and there is no description.

Comment: Did you try clearing your browser's cache?

Comment: You are saying that og:url is localhost. So Facebook will try to load it and fail. You need to have og:url to be something Facebook can scrape